# ¿Cómo colocar una etiqueta como oculta para que se muestre al presionar un botón?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

He escrito el contenido "oculto" y el botón de esta forma:

```
<button id="mostrarMsj">Mostrar mensaje</button>  
<div class="oculto">  
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>  
</div>
```

Y el código en JQuery de esta manera:

```
 $('#mostrarMsj').on('click', function(){
    $('.oculto').show(0, function(){
        console.log('Aqui va el resto de mi código');
    })
 });
```

Sin embargo, el mensaje aparece cuando ejecuto el código.

Comment: Hola puedes re formular tu pregunta y si tienes ejemplo del código, colócalo para poderte ayudar. También te recomiendo que leas como es para formular una pregunta.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Te invito a que conozcas como funciona la comunidad visitando la [presentación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). A continuación, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta siguiendo las [directrices de calidad](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hola Thainan. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Creo que una pregunta de este estilo, si bien es totalmente válida, _debería_ dar un poco más de información a quien quiera ayudarte (ayúdanos a ayudarte). Para alguien que no está en tu lugar, la pregunta da muy poco contexto; no explica qué se está haciendo, por qué estás interesado en entenderlo, ni nada que nos de alguna pista del objetivo. Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo más de información, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un __[mcve]__ en todas las preguntas.

Comment: Que es lo que no esta claro, si me parece muy simple, cuando pulse un botón que se despliegue un mensaje, que esta oculto.

Comment: No todas las preguntas pueden ser como las queremos.

Comment: Te recomendaria especificar y aclarar, que debe hacer el mensaje, que hace el boton, podrias poner un poco de codigo para poder ver.

Answer (score 3):

Ejemplo funcional utilizando [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com). desarrollas mas escribiendo menos y lo mejor!!... es multi plataforma:

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    $("#mensaje").show(0, function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#mensaje").hide(1000);
      }, 2000);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Mostrar Mensaje</button>
<div id="mensaje" style="display:none">
  <h1>Mensaje oculto!! ;))</h1>
  <h2>Hola! Hola! Hola!
    <h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Así si que funciona. Saludos
```

```css
.oculto{
    display: none;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<button id="mostrarMsj">Mostrar Mensaje</button>
<div class="oculto"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
 
<script>
$( "#mostrarMsj" ).click(function() {
  $( ".oculto" ).show( 0, function(){
        console.log('Aqui va el resto de mi código');
    });
 
});
</script>
```